# How to create a SQLite database in Qt

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

I am trying to create a SQLite database in Qt. Here is my code:

```
QDir databasePath;
QString path = databasePath.currentPath()+"myDb.db";
QSqlDatabase dbConnection = QSqlDatabase:addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(path);
db.open();
```

There are no errors when running the code, but I can't find the database I created in the path I defined.
Does this actually create the database or does it just do some initialization?

If it does not create the database then how do I create the database within the application itself? (I am not talking about insertion.)

Comment: Hard code the path instead of creating a variable, and test again.  That is one way to ensure it isn't a code or bad string issue as opposed to some other issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: this is actually solved the problem of the location thank you very much

Comment: The most common mistake here is to get the path wrong.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should also create query which will create not empty database and use correct name of variable(in your code you use `dbConnection` firstly and after that - `db`. For example:

```
QString path = "path";
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");//not dbConnection
db.setDatabaseName(path);
db.open();
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("create table person "
          "(id integer primary key, "
          "firstname varchar(20), "
          "lastname varchar(30), "
          "age integer)");
```

Comment: Oh I see, I didnot notice he is using different names, sorry. Hoever, I am having a problem using the same code, after hard-coded the path like this: `QString path="c://Users//me//Document//workapce//myproject//databse.db"` my app crashes. when debugging it just exit with crash .. what might be the problem

Comment: Is it possible to connect to a db file with a username and password?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger Try this `open()` method http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#open-1

Answer (score 2):

His mistake was,

```
QDir databasePath;
QString path = databasePath.currentPath()+"/myDb.db"; // Not "myDb.db"
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(path);
db.open();
QSqlQuery query; // And he should insert some data, as the answer above mentioned
query.exec("create table person "
          "(id integer primary key, "
          "firstname varchar(20), "
          "lastname varchar(30), "
          "age integer)");
```

And the database file `myDb.db` is created in `build` directory not in his `source` code directory.